# Which sensor should I use to recognize just humans? (not all of the obstacles)

Tags: sensor, temperature, detection, movement

I would like to make a social distance meter and the device should only avoid from humans, not the obstacles. I'll use an ultrasonic sensor and a PIR sensor but I'm not sure it will be enough. Do I need to use a temperature sensor too? But not sure how I can implement the temperature sensor from social distancing approach. Do you know any specific sensor or method to detect only humans?

Comment: a *sensor* isn't what you're looking for – it's the post-processing of sensor data that does recognition.

Comment: There have been many questions on this site about various techniques to achieve the same end. Most of them are doomed to failure. Yours will really struggle with trying to do 360° cover and match up responses from the range sensor with data from something like an infrared camera. The processing will be very complex and, judging by your question, beyond your present capability. Recommendation: forget about this project. If it was practical then similar devices would be on sale already.

Comment: You are right but I should work on this topic due to lecture requirements. I think I may change this project to an AI project and use a camera and OpenCV to observe and measure the distance between humans.

Comment: In Terminator they used dogs... very good at detecting humans...

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, infrared sensors are used for this, they also work in the dark.

When searching for human sensors, I also came for example to this sensor:
[AK9750 Human Detection IR Sensor Module](https://www.digikey.nl/en/product-highlight/a/akm-semi/ak9750-human-detection-ir-sensor-module?utm_adgroup=General&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_EN_Product&utm_term=&productid=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwuL_8BRCXARIsAGiC51AahujZCeuXlcy1RXSmzCsV4CnTunyXj_oI66Yzq755r8wt_S8Db50aAg0REALw_wcB). This sensor has a range of 2-3 meters which should be sufficient for social distancing measurements. Probably there are more similar sensors.